# Object destructuring to update attributes

Tags: typescript

What does syntax like the below achieve?

```
  return {
    ...state,
    loggedIn: true,
    user: action.payload.user,
  };
```

Assume, state's type is:

```
export interface State {
  loggedIn: boolean;
  user: User | null;
}
```

Is it way to add/update attribute values in a object?

I found the this example here: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/example-app/app/auth/reducers/auth.ts

Comment: It's a non-standardised yet syntax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals

Comment: it's the shortest way to set `user` and `loggedIn` while preserving any additional properties received in the `state` parameter (which can be anything that `extends interface State`), **without modifying** received `state` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does syntax like the below achieve?

It spreads the props from `state` into a new object, and then sets `loggedIn` to true and `user` to `action.payload.user`

## More

The syntax `...foo` is Object Spread. I wrote about it too https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/spread-operator.html